# iOS: Presenting a spinning wheel while NSFetchResultsController is performing a fetch

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate a `UITableView`. The fetch take some time so I would like to present a spinning wheel to the user while the fetch is under way.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start your spinner in the Main thread and push the "heavy work" for a secondary thread. When the work is done, stop the spinner. You can achieve that with something like this:

```
    // Start the spinning here.
    [mySpinner startAnimating];
    // Declare the queue
    dispatch_queue_t workingQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    // it's not, so we will start a background process to calculate it and not block the UI
    dispatch_async(workingQueue, 
                   ^{
                      // Some heavy work here.

                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
                          // stop the spinner here
                          [mySpinner stopAnimating];
                       });
                   });
```

Doing the following in the Main thread wont make you accomplish what you want:

```
Start Spinner => Heavy work => Stop Spinner
```

When the Heavy work begins, it will block your UI thread, so you won't actually see the `UIActivityMonitor` animating.

To finish I would advise you using [this](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) as spinner.

Comment: This works for me. I wasn't sure that the `NSFetchedResultsController` would like to be perform the fetch on a separate thread.

Comment: Qualquer dúvida é só dizeres, Tiago. Acho que ainda não estás a ver quem eu sou... :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several way to do that :

had a `UIBarItem` if you use UINavigationBar and set customView to `UIActivityIndicator` at the beginning of your function and hide it a the end.

Create a "modal" view with a `UIActivityIndicator` at the center of the view, and add this subview to your table view and remove it a the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

formally just you can use the UIActivityIndicatorView to present the wheel and for some good and delicate way use the MBHoods from [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/MBProgressHUD) download the demo app [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/MBProgressHUD)